# Which part should be changed in the remote theme of jekyll to enlarge window size of the post?

Tags: jekyll, jekyll-theme

For building web-page, I use the github pages and jekyll remote theme.
I am not familiar with jekyll and remote theme, so cannot know
which part should be modified and which part cannot be 
in the remote theme.

Also, I am currently using the *so-simple-theme* as a remote theme
and want to change the layout of the blog postings 
to make the article section wider (at default, most of the pages are filled with empty space, so cannot see the code very clearly) 
To make the post section itself to be wider, which file and content should be changed?

Answer (score 0):

My first pass on the `so-simple-theme` [code base](https://github.com/mmistakes/so-simple-theme), it looks like there are some preset `max-width` for blog postings.  It uses a SCSS variable `$main-max-width` [code here](https://github.com/mmistakes/so-simple-theme/blob/afc3a8b984e06a6bcae88712fe9e0af2419bae62/_sass/so-simple/_page.scss#L204-L214) that is set in `_variables.scss` [code here](https://github.com/mmistakes/so-simple-theme/blob/afc3a8b984e06a6bcae88712fe9e0af2419bae62/_sass/so-simple/_variables.scss#L85) these preset max width variables [code here](https://github.com/mmistakes/so-simple-theme/blob/afc3a8b984e06a6bcae88712fe9e0af2419bae62/_sass/so-simple/_variables.scss#L5-L9).

I was able to increase the list of posts' width by setting `$main-max-width: $large !default;` in `_variables.scss`.

## With default `$medium`

[image]

## With `$large`

[image]